# .bat file that opens cmd in certain location without admin permission

Tags: batch-file

I'm really new to this but I found a bat file online with the following code in it:

```
@echo off
cls
title Batchcc Prompt C:
color 0a
cls
:cmd
set /p "cmd=%CD%>"
%cmd%
echo.
goto cmd
```

I'm looking for a way to open Command Prompt w/o admin access in C: however this one opens in whatever location the bat is stored in. Is there a way to edit this to open in C:? Or is there another way to do the same thing?

Comment: Create a shortcut to `CMD.exe` on your desktop. Right Click the shortcut and select properties. Then select the Shortcut tab. Change the `Start in:` option to `C:\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the simplest way would be `cd /d`

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\
cls
title Batchcc Prompt C:
color 0a
cls
:cmd
set /p "cmd=%CD%>"
%cmd%
echo.
goto cmd
```